# Multiple autocompletes and finding selected

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am having trouble finding where jquery is setting the value of autocomplete. I know that it uses a combobox in the background to control what is searchable for the autocomplete. I have been messing with the ui.item and have not had any luck. The only way I can think of doing this is by creating an array and saving the data off to that when somethings changed. I would think that jquery has to be setting the value per box somewhere but I can not find it in the html. You can see what I am dealing with at [practiscore test](http://practiscore.com/test.php). In the end what I am wanting to get is a way to save the current values off to database so I can save the state.

I am using the jquery autocomplete code from the jquery website found [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the combobox approach, selecting an item updates the selection in the hidden `select` element.

You can get the values like this:

```
$('select[name=squad1]').val()
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. I had to change some of my code to adjust the name for each box.

Answer (score 0):

you can read it like a normal select box:

```
$("select").bind("change, function() {
    alert( $(this).find(":selected").val() );
});
```

Or submit it like a normal form.